# error Unexpected token < in json response

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

Iam trying to get in users information into database via javaScript file by linking it to a .php file its throwing "unexpected token <" but when i directly give action as .php      its working out fine i think problem is with .js file is with please help me resolve this issue.pardon if am wrong..!!

**.html**

```
                             <form id="form" name = "form" method = "POST" action="form_banking1.php" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <!--<h1>Please fill the below details</h1>-->
                                <fieldset>
                                    <!--<h2>Account Information</h2>-->
                                    <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Current address" class="form-control required" id="ca" name="ca" required="">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="House no" class="form-control required" id="hno" name="hno" required="">
                                            </div>  
                                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Road no" class="form-control required" id="rno" name="rno" required="">
                                            </div>  
                                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Location" class="form-control required" id="location" name="location" required="">
                                            </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                            <select type="text" class="form-control required" name="country" required="">
                                            <option value="">Country</option>
                                            <option value="1">India</option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                        <select type="text" class="form-control required" id="state" name="state" required="">
                                            <option value="">State</option>
                                            <option value="1">Karnataka</option>

.                                            </select>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                            <select type="text" class="form-control required" id="city" name="city" required="">
                                            <option value="">City</option>
                                            <option value="1">Bengaluru</option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Pin no" class="form-control required"  id="pin" name="pin" required="">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                            <select type="text" class="form-control required" id="doctitle" name="doctitle" required="">
                                            <option value="">Document Title</option>
                                            <option value="1">Aadhar Card</option>
                                            <option value="2">Pan Card</option>
                                            <option value="3">Ration Card</option>
                                            <option value="4">Green Card</option>
                                            <option value="5">Social Security Card</option>
                                            <option value="6">Voter ID</option>
                                            <option value="7">Driving License</option>
                                            <option value="8">Add New</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Document no" class="form-control required"  id="docno" name="docno" required="">
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Issued Authority" class="form-control required"  id="ia" name="ia" required="">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                           <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Expiry" class="form-control required"  id="doe" name="doe" required="">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Passport no" class="form-control required" id="pno" name="pno" required="">
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Issued Authority" class="form-control required"  id="pissuedby" name="pissuedby" required="">
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Expiry" class="form-control required" id="pdoe" name="pdoe" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Visa no" class="form-control required" id="vno" name="vno" required="">
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Issued Authority" class="form-control required"  id="vissuedby" name="vissuedby" required="">
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Expiry" class="form-control required" id="vdoe" name="vdoe" required="">
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control " type="file" name = "doc" id = "doc" required="">
                                        </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <input style="width:100%" type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Save"  class="btn btn-success">
                                            </div><!--==== End col-sm-4 form-group==--> 

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                                                    <i class="" style="font-size: 180px;color: #e5e5e5 "></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </fieldset>

                                </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

**.js**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "form_citizenship.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",   

                success: function(json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                    }else{
                        alert(json.docno);
                    }
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

**.php**

```
       <?php
session_start();
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','miisky');

$response = array();

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){

    $error_flag = false;
    /*foreach($_POST as $value){
        if(empty($value)){
            $error_flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }*/

    if(!$error_flag){

        //receiving post parameters
        $ca =$_POST['ca'];
        $hno = trim($_POST['hno']);
        $rno = trim($_POST['rno']);
        $location = trim($_POST['location']);
        $country = trim($_POST['country']);
        $state = trim($_POST['state']);
        $city = trim($_POST['city']);
        $pin = trim($_POST['pin']);
        $doctitle = trim($_POST['doctitle']);
        $docno = trim($_POST['docno']);
        $ia = trim($_POST['ia']);
        $doe = trim($_POST['doe']);
        $pno = trim($_POST['pno']);
        $pissuedby = trim($_POST['pissuedby']);
        $pdoe = trim($_POST['pdoe']);
        $vno = trim($_POST['vno']);
        $vissuedby = trim($_POST['vissuedby']);
        $vdoe = trim($_POST['vdoe']);

        if(isset($_FILES["doc"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["doc"]["name"])){

            //image insertion
            $target_dir = 'doc_uploads/';
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["doc"]["name"]);

            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["doc"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false){

                if (!file_exists($target_file)){

                    if($_FILES["doc"]["size"] <= 2097152){

                        $permissible_images = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
                        if(in_array($imageFileType, $permissible_images)){

                            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["doc"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

                                // create a new user profile
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO citizen_info(ca, hno, rno, location, country, state, city, pin, doctitle, docno, ia, doe, pno, pissuedby, pdoe, vno, vissuedby, vdoe, doc, created_at) VALUES ('$ca', '$hno', '$rno', '$location', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$pin', '$doctitle', '$docno', '$ia', '$doe', '$pno', '$pissuedby', '$pdoe', '$vno', '$vissuedby', '$vdoe', '$target_file', NOW())";
                                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                                    $response["error"] = false;
                                    $response['docno'] = $docno;
                                    echo json_encode($response);

                                }else{
                                    $response["error"] = true;
                                    $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                                    echo json_encode($response);
                                }
                            }else{
                                // Throw Error Here
                                $response["error"] = true;
                                $response["error_msg"] = "File could not be uploaded";
                                echo json_encode($response);
                            }

                        }else{
                            $response["error"] = true;
                            $response["error_msg"] = "Only jpg, png and gif images are allowed";
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }

                    }else{
                        $response["error"] = true;
                        $response["error_msg"] = "file size is above 2MB";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }

                }else{
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "file already exists";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }

            }else{
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "invalid image format";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

        }else{
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Empty file";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }else{
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Few fields are missing";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}else{
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Database connection failed";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Using synchronous calls is a bad practice.

Comment: My bet is you are not returning valid JSON back and from the looks of your PHP, you are not.

Comment: but sir am encoding the $response..!!

Comment: You have echos everywhere. Look at what is being returned from the server in the console.

Comment: but sir when i directly give in action as form_citizenship.php in html its giving out result in json format..!!

Comment: @krishna Please update your question with the entire HTML form so that it could be easy to recreate the issue.

Comment: okay sure sir ill..!!

Comment: sir i have updated..!!

Comment: @krishna Sorry I didn't get notified of your comment. I'll write an answer very soon, but first clarify these things, what is the logic behind this while loop, `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ... }`? After INSERT operation what's the point's of this query, `$sql = "SELECT * FROM citizen_info WHERE docno = '$docno' LIMIT 1";` Are you sure these are all correct?

Comment: Okay sir definitely I'll inspect them once and try to change it and if you see that code is not accordingly,  please correct me ...!!

Comment: @krishna I've added an answer. Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things I would like to point out.

- Your form validation `var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();` won't work because you didn't include `required` attribute in your `<input ...>` elements. Include them like this:

  ```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Current address" class="form-control required" id="ca" name="ca" required>
  ```
- Use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent your form from being submitted in the first place.
- If you're uploading file through AJAX, use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. But keep in mind that old browsers don't support FormData object. FormData support starts from the following desktop browsers versions: IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+.
- Set the following options, `processData: false` and `contentType: false` in your AJAX request. Refer [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to know what these do.
- And finally, do proper validation of your form inputs on `form_citizenship.php` page because right now it's a complete mess.

So your jQuery should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "form_citizenship.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",   

                success: function(json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                    }else{
                        alert(json.docno);
                    }
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

And process your AJAX request like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','miisky');

    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){

        $error_flag = false;
        foreach($_POST as $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                $error_flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$error_flag){

            //receiving post parameters
            $ca =$_POST['ca'];
            $hno = trim($_POST['hno']);
            $rno = trim($_POST['rno']);
            $location = trim($_POST['location']);
            $country = trim($_POST['country']);
            $state = trim($_POST['state']);
            $city = trim($_POST['city']);
            $pin = trim($_POST['pin']);
            $doctitle = trim($_POST['doctitle']);
            $docno = trim($_POST['docno']);
            $ia = trim($_POST['ia']);
            $doe = trim($_POST['doe']);
            $pno = trim($_POST['pno']);
            $pissuedby = trim($_POST['pissuedby']);
            $pdoe = trim($_POST['pdoe']);
            $vno = trim($_POST['vno']);
            $vissuedby = trim($_POST['vissuedby']);
            $vdoe = trim($_POST['vdoe']);

            if(isset($_FILES["doc"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["doc"]["name"])){

                //image insertion
                $target_dir = 'doc_uploads/';
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["doc"]["name"]);

                $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["doc"]["tmp_name"]);
                if($check !== false){

                    if (!file_exists($target_file)){

                        if($_FILES["doc"]["size"] <= 2097152){

                            $permissible_images = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
                            if(in_array($imageFileType, $permissible_images)){

                                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["doc"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

                                    // create a new user profile
                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO citizen_info(ca, hno, rno, location, country, state, city, pin, doctitle, docno, ia, doe, pno, pissuedby, pdoe, vno, vissuedby, vdoe, doc, created_at) VALUES ('$ca', '$hno', '$rno', '$location', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$pin', '$doctitle', '$docno', '$ia', '$doe', '$pno', '$pissuedby', '$pdoe', '$vno', '$vissuedby', '$vdoe', '$target_file', NOW())";
                                    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                                        $response["error"] = false;
                                        $response['docno'] = $docno;
                                        echo json_encode($response);

                                    }else{
                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                        $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    // Throw Error Here
                                    $response["error"] = true;
                                    $response["error_msg"] = "File could not be uploaded";
                                    echo json_encode($response);
                                }

                            }else{
                                $response["error"] = true;
                                $response["error_msg"] = "Only jpg, png and gif images are allowed";
                                echo json_encode($response);
                            }

                        }else{
                            $response["error"] = true;
                            $response["error_msg"] = "file size is above 2MB";
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }

                    }else{
                        $response["error"] = true;
                        $response["error_msg"] = "file already exists";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }

                }else{
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "invalid image format";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }

            }else{
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Empty file";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

        }else{
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Few fields are missing";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }else{
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Database connection failed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir...lots of things still to be done an to learn...!!! Thank you for everything

Comment: @krishna Glad I could help. :)

Comment: sir can you help..!! the code above when executed its still showing "few fields missing".

Comment: but when i say to execute the server side php file its showing no fields were missing..!! how to resolve this sir..??

Comment: @krishna That's because you've probably left one or more input fields blank. All fields are mandatory. Fill all the input fields, select an image to upload and then hit *Save* button.

Comment: sir i have updated my code which is poping up the alert "few fields are mssing" even though i fill in all fields please help me resolve this sir..!!

Comment: @krishna I've tested this on my system and it's working fine. You've definitely left one or more fields blank. Is there any *optional* field in the form? Just for the sake of debugging remove this `foreach` loop, `foreach($_POST as $value){ ... }` and run the application again.

Comment: sir as you said i commented out the foreach loop.. now again its showing "SyntaxError:Unexpected Token <" cant understand whats the problem..!!

Comment: sir i have updated out my entire code including front and back-end process..!!which is giving out the error..!!plz help sir

Comment: @krishna You've completely changed the question. It's out of my hands now. Like I said, with respect to [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34877118/5) the solution works fine. BTW what are the other js codes doing there in *.html*? Debug incrementally. Include *only the essential* HTML, JavaScript and PHP part and test it.

Comment: exactly sir i commented out some .js files and it started working..!! but one problem is its not performing action in form tag..!!

Comment: @krishna *...its not performing action in form tag* doesn't give me any clue what's wrong. Please explain your issue.

Comment: sir i mean its showing me the pop up of docno..!! but it is restricting the action="form_banking1.php" in <form> tag as mentioned in above code..!

Comment: @krishna That's because of this `e.preventDefault();`, I've mentioned it in my answer also. If after receiving the responce on *success* you want to redirect the user to *form_banking1.php* page then place it on places where you would receive errors, like: `if(json.error){ /* here*/ }else{ ... }` and `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /*here*/ }`

Comment: Got it sir..!! now working smoothly..!! some prob with my edditor..!!

Comment: @krishna Happy to hear. :)

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens due to the javascript expecting a json response, and server throwing some error enclosed with `'<html></html>'`.

Check inside the chrome inspector if the ajax response is correct.
Headsup:

Inside Chrome`>` <kbd>F12</kbd> `>` Network `>` XHR.

Check the response as follows..

```
              $.ajax({
                url: "form_citizenship.php",
                type: "POST",
                //form serialization of the all parameters
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
                async: false,
                //data passed in json
                dataType: "JSON",
                /*Give out the alert box
                to display the results*/                
                success: function (json){
                    console.log(json); // <<< you can view in the console the response.
                    .......
                },
                //through out error from back-end if exist
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: but sir when i directly give in action as form_citizenship.php in html its giving out result in json format..!!

Comment: try `console.log`(ing) the "json" success return variable. and see if correct the data is correct json.

Comment: am new to this may i know how..??

Comment: Updated my answer, Also I am still unable to understand, why are you calling the `$('#form').submit();` on success function since the the whole point of making the ajax post call is "posting" the serialized form data, so in a way, you are just double posting the form.

Comment: sir now i have updated main js code...but its still giving out a alert pop up  "Unexpected token <"

Comment: Ok, Now It clearly means the ajax request encountered the error while processing the response, since that alert which you speak of, is inside the error handling part of the code, pretty sure the problem is with the response being returned by php.

Comment: sir but as i updated my code i even encoded every response of php in json format as seen above..can you please point out where is the problem exactly..?? because when i give out html action = "form_citizenship.php" its giving out output as"{"error":false}{"error":false,"docno":"kjhkjhk"}"  and data getting saved in database, dont know whats problem with .js

Comment: But the json response that you posted above `{"error":false}{"error":false,"docno":"kjhkjhk"}` is in invalid format if its the whole response!!

Comment: but i have used json_encode($response); in above code so its giving out the

Comment: Ok, but, what is happening is that there are two `json_encode` echo being outputted, what you should do is first make an array/object of all the data that you wish to echo then `json_encode` and echo it. and just to be safer add a `die();` after `json_encode` so the php execution stops rightaway.